# How do I create a subclass of TabPage that I can edit like a UserControl?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms, custom-controls

I want to create a subclass of TabPage that contains some control, and I want to control the layout and properties of those controls through the designer.  However, if I open my subclass in the designer, I can't position them like I could on a UserControl.  I don't want to have to create a TabPage with an UserControl instance on it, I want to design the TabPage directly.

How do I do that?  I've tried changing the Designer and DesignerCategory attributes, but I haven't found any values that help.

Answer (score 9):

I've had a similar problem in the past.

What i did first was switch from inheriting Usercontrol to tabpage like so

class UserInterface : UserControl // Do designer bit then change it to

class UserInterface : TabPage

Second i Just put all my controls and stuff in the usercontrol and docked that into a tabpage.

third i've made a generic class that takes any usercontrol and does the docking automatically.

so you can take your 'UserInterface' class and just get a type that you can add to a System.Windows.Forms.TabControl

```
public class UserTabControl<T> : TabPage
    where T : UserControl, new ()
{
    private T _userControl;
    public T UserControl 
    { 
        get{ return _userControl;}
        set
        {          
            _userControl = value;
            OnUserControlChanged(EventArgs.Empty);
        }
    }
    public event EventHandler UserControlChanged;
    protected virtual void OnUserControlChanged(EventArgs e)
    {
        //add user control docked to tabpage
        this.Controls.Clear();      
        UserControl.Dock = DockStyle.Fill;
        this.Controls.Add(UserControl);

        if (UserControlChanged != null)
        {
            UserControlChanged(this, e);
        }
    }

    public UserTabControl() : this("UserTabControl")
    {
    }

    public UserTabControl(string text) 
        : this( new T(),text )
    {
    }

    public UserTabControl(T userControl) 
        : this(userControl, userControl.Name)
    {
    }

    public UserTabControl(T userControl, string tabtext)
        : base(tabtext)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        UserControl = userControl;  
    }

    private void InitializeComponent()
    {
        this.SuspendLayout();
        // 
        // UserTabControl
        // 

        this.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Transparent;
        this.Padding = new System.Windows.Forms.Padding(3);
        this.UseVisualStyleBackColor = true;
        this.ResumeLayout(false);
    }
}
```

Comment: The really important part is to change from TabPage to UserControl. For some reason Visual Studio will not display the control in the designer if it is inheriting from TabPage. Changing to UserControl solves this immediately. Now it also shows up in the toolbox.

Comment: This looks like a very clever solution to my problem, but I am not grasping how to fully implement. Namely the last step "so you can take your 'UserInterface' class and just get a type that you can add to a System.Windows.Forms.TabControl". How do I do this? Do I have to hand-edit the designer.cs code for main dialog?

Answer (score 1):

I handle this by designing the pages themselves as individual forms, which are then hosted inside tab pages at runtime.

How do you put a form inside a `TabPage`?

```
form.TopLevel = false;
form.Parent = tabPage;
form.FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.None; // otherwise you get a form with a 
                                             //  title bar inside the tab page, 
                                             //  which is a little odd
```

Comment: I don't see an improvement on using a UserControl.

Comment: I agree. Using a Form is excessive, just use a UserControl.

Comment: The sample code is not enough to get a Form to display in a TabPage. I tried it, it compiled and ran, but the tab page was empty.